# Will mutex unlock implicity notify other threads?

Tags: c++, mutex, condition-variable

Imaging we have a condition variable **cv_** associated with a mutex **mtx_**

Thread t1 has an unique_lock **ul** associated with **mtx_** now and it has **cv_** now, while other threads are **cv_.wait(unique_lock(mtx_), &{}**

if t1 doesn't explicitly call **cv_.notify_all()**, instead, it calls **mtx_.unlock()**

will this implicitly notify other threads who are waiting for **cv_**?

```
void worker() {
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> ul(mtx_);
        cv_.wait(ul, [&]() {
           some condition
        });

        ul.unlock(); // 

        doing somthing ...

        ul.lock();
        update shared resource
        ul.unlock();
        cv_.notify_all();
    }
}
```

through my test, seemingly the ul.unlock() in the middle notifies other threads that are waiting.

Comment: No, `unlock` doesn't by itself notify any condition variables. It may only seem like it does. In your example, if the thread doing `update shared resource` gets the lock first, before the thread that's about to wait, then by the time that thread gets to `cv_.wait`, the condition is already satisfied and it doesn't actually block on the condition variable. This may look like it has been woken by `unlock`, but in reality it never slept in the first place.

Comment: On the other hand, if the waiting thread gets to `wait` first, while the condition is still false, and does go to sleep, then `unlock` on the other thread will not wake it up. `notify_one` or `notify_all` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, @IgorTandetnik for the detailed explanation, I see the problem, other threads are not necessarily waiting for the cv, instead they are just trying to obtain the lock. That explains why!